# FromBody not binding string parameter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have an issue similar to [ASP.NET MVC 4 RC Web API Parameter Binding Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158617/asp-net-mvc-4-rc-web-api-parameter-binding-issue), but I'm trying to solve it by using the [FromBody] attribute.

Fiddler reports the following request (excluding irrelevant bits like User Agent String)

```
PUT http://localhost:82/api/account/shoppinglistitems HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:82
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 11
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

query=apple
```

My controller action is

```
[HttpPut]
public ShoppingListItemWebModel CreateShoppingListItem([FromBody]string query) {
    // query is null
}
```

I could wrap the parameter in a complex type, but that seems like a hack to fix the issue. Or I could put the query in the URI, but that doesn't fit the pattern of the rest of the API. Is it possible to do it this way? If so, where is my mistake?

Comment: The title says POST, but the question says PUT. Just a little misleading.

Comment: Related question for Asp.Net Core https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952002/asp-net-core-mvc-how-to-get-raw-json-bound-to-a-string-without-a-type

Answer (score 45, accepted):

change your request to be

```
PUT http://localhost:82/api/account/shoppinglistitems HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:82
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 11
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

=apple
```

notice the lack of "query"

Comment: Any idea how to extract multiple strings from the body?

Comment: not possible, you'd have to use complex type. 
Mike Stall has a great blog on that I recommend it to anyone interested in Web API model binding http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx

Comment: of course you still use [FromUri] to pass multiple simple type parameters

Comment: This is not possible other than how Filip shows. This is by design although it might change since a lot of people seem to have asked for it. Original discussion [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/359687).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I also found you can parse the content yourself by using `Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result`, if you don't want to create a model.

Comment: Thanks @Kurt for pointing this method. After several attempts, this was the only solution that helped in my case (wanted to post a json value as a string in the server).

Comment: I understand this is an old thread but as I had the same problem and the solution is so counter intuitive I wonder if you know why this is the case? Can you point me to some articles on that?

Answer (score 23):

If you're using AngularJS instead of jQuery you might want to opt for the following alternative, since AngularJS uses content type `application/json` by default.

```
PUT http://localhost:82/api/account/shoppinglistitems HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:82
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 7
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

'apple'
```

Notice that the value is wrapped in string quotes (either single or double).

Comment: In angular, you can get the quote wrapping by using [angular.toJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson) to encode your payload.