# POST parameters in CURL

Tags: post, curl, asp.net-web-api

I am attempting to use CURL to send a simple POST parameter (an int) to an ASP.NET web api controller POST method like so:

```
curl -d "id=1" --ntlm --user <user>:<pass> http://dev.test.local/api/test
```

Is this the correct way to attach data to the POST for Curl? I can contact the URL fine but it seems the parameter 'id' doesn't get passed because i get the following error returned from the server:

```
"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nulla
ble type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String Post(Int32)' in 'Test.Si
te.Controllers.TestController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type,
a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."
```

My POST method in the OrderController is as follows:

```
    // POST api/test
    public string Post(int id)
    {
        return "Post successful";
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you're curious exactly what `curl` is sending you can run `curl --trace-ascii curl.log -d id=1 ...` and then look in `curl.log` (which will show you that `curl` is generating a perfectly normal `POST` request)

Comment: Ok, i had a look at the log and the error is the same one listed above?

Comment: @davey1990, is it possible that the data sent by curl is being interpreted as a string, and not as an integer, and therefore, is being nulled out somehow by .net? Consider changing your function to accept a String instead and let us know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would use a simple DTO and call via JSON.

route:

```
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
            defaults: new {   }
        );
```

controller & DTO:

```
[DataContract]
public class valueDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class TestController : ApiController
{
    // POST api/values
    public string Post(valueDto value)
    {
        return string.Format("Post successful {0}", value.id);
    }
}
```

Call with curl:

```
curl -d "{ "id": 1 }" --ntlm --user <user>:<pass> http://dev.test.local/api/test -H "Content-Type:application/json"
```

*But*

Just to follow on a little from tugberk's answer and referencing another [answer](http://forums.asp.net/t/1812226.aspx/1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515319/asp-net-web-api-post-frombody-not-binding-string-parameter) .

When you use the FromBody attribute you will also need to send the "Content-Type" as Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded. You will also need to change the call not have the "id=1" and instead use "=1" e.g.

```
curl -d "=1" --ntlm --user <user>:<pass> http://dev.test.local/api/test -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, this way is correct. I have chosen to create my own Model object and then have the parameters bound automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that simple types such as `int`, `string`, etc. cannot be model-bound with the data from the message body unless you tell it explicitly as below:

```
public string Post([FromBody]int id)
{
    return "Post successful";
}
```

The other solution is that you can ask these types of values from `RouteData` or query string.

Comment: This way also works tugberk for simple types, however i was eventually going to build up to posting complex data types. Thanks!