# Post Parameter is always null, c# api controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

```
public void PostImport([FromBody]string file)
{}
```

By debugging I have entered method and see that file is always null, used a number of different requests, one of these should work (have also tried both with capital a for Application/json)? :

```
C:\>curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"\":\"myStr\"}" http://localhost:61393/api/admin/import
```

and

```
C:\>curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"file\":\"myStr\"}" http://localhost:61393/api/admin/import
```

My routes are set up as below

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "DefaultApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Try tweak curl arguments to get similar query: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11517468/458723.  The symptoms are same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FromBody not binding string parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515319/frombody-not-binding-string-parameter)

Comment: @Kirill yeah thats what the first curl is doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d "=myStr" http://localhost:61393/api/admin/import
```

Instead of Content type header use accept header, it should work.

Comment: thanks. I find this very weird, why doesn't m$ support valid json ?

Answer (score 0):

You should send an header for xhr ("XMLHttpRequest"), only then you would be able to hit your web-api.
Try adding below header and run it.

`"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"`

Comment: I'm not sure this is answer to the question.  @NimChimpsky says he can stop debugger inside PostImport so request definitely reaches application.

Comment: @Kirill, I agree with you. I thought in web-api there may be restriction to populate params only when it is a XHR request.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your curl syntax is correct. This is the syntax from the curl [manual](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html):

```
curl -d "name=Rafael%20Sagula&phone=3320780" \ 
            http://www.where.com/guest.cgi
```

Did you try another rest client to test your application (e.g. Fiddler)?