# MVC4 Web API simple parameter types are null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm writing a service using MVC 4 Web API to receive a `POST` from a third party service. It's a simple post with a string parameter in the body that looks like `key=value`.

This is pretty much the default controller created by Visual Studio:

```
// POST api/register
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
}
```

If I post the parameter in the body as `key=value`, the parameter is always `NULL` when it hits the service.

```
POST http://localhost:1750/api/Register HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 15
Host: localhost:1750
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

value=abcdefg
```

If I remove the key and only post `=value` then value comes through.

```
POST http://localhost:1750/api/Register HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 15
Host: localhost:1750
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

=abcdefg
```

The problem is the 3rd party service is posting `key=value`. How can I get my service to work properly?

Comment: rename parameter to `public void Post([FromBody]string key)`?

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried. It doesn't matter what I name the parameter.

Comment: I'm sure you've seen post where you got your workaround from, but for others following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515319/frombody-not-binding-string-parameter contains some useful links too...

Comment: I've created a generic http handler which is probably more appropriate for my scenario. I'll attempt to go through the answers below at another time.

Answer (score 0):

What is your default MediaType ?

**1 solution**

Make a class

```
 public Class Item {

     public string Value { get; set;}

    }
```

Then

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]Item item)
{ 
  // item.Value should have your data.
}
```

**2nd solution** If you cannot control how data is coming, can you ask them to encode text when they are sending?

In that can you can receive as a string as value%3dxyz
Then you can receive on your string variable and manipulate by decoding the same.

**3rd solution**

Use your Custom Serializer something like this:

```
  public class CustomJsonMediaFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
    {
     private JsonSerializerSettings _jsonSerializerSettings;

        public CustomJsonMediaFormatter ()
        {
            _jsonSerializerSettings = CreateDefaultSerializerSettings();
        }

  private object ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
        {

var contentHeaders = content == null ? null : content.Headers;

            // If content length is 0 then return default value for this type
            if (contentHeaders != null && contentHeaders.ContentLength == 0)
            {
                return GetDefaultValueForType(type);
            }

            // Get the character encoding for the content
            var effectiveEncoding = SelectCharacterEncoding(contentHeaders);

            try
            {
                using (var reader = (new StreamReader(readStream, effectiveEncoding)))
                {
                    var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    var jo = JObject.Parse(json);
                           // jo has got your value=xyz manipulate and feed back.
                }
             }
```