# REST service parameter not received - change the controller to match the calling routine

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

I have a calling routine that I cannot change (unlike the suggested [FromBody not binding string parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515319/frombody-not-binding-string-parameter) and [ASP.NET web api cannot get application/x-www-form-urlencoded HTTP POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369361/asp-net-web-api-cannot-get-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-http-post)) and need to rather adjust the controller to match.  When debugging the controller, the variable `msg` is `null` even though data is being passed on the wire. The objective is to allow an XML file to be sent to the controller.

What needs to be changed in the controller so that the data is received?

**API Controller**

```
    public class ApiInterchangeController : ApiBaseController
    {
       [HttpPost]
       public HttpResponseMessage ServiceCallAction([FromBody]string msg)
       {
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg))
           {
               var httpError = new HttpError("No Data Sent");
               return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, httpError);
           }
       }
    }
```

**Calling routine**

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath("Temp") + "\\";
string fileName = "SampleData2.txt";
string xmlMsg = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath + fileName);

// sample data for point of reference
// xmlMsg = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n<DATA ID=\"25379\">\r\n</DATA>"

string URL = "http://localhost:53417/API/ApiInterchange/ServiceCallAction";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
byte[] byteData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("msg=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(xmlMsg));
request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

using (var postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
   postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
   postStream.Close();
}

var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Comment: @BrunoJoaquim _"a calling routine that I CANNOT change"_

Comment: possible duplicate of [FromBody not binding string parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11515319/327101)

Comment: @LukasKubis "a calling routine that I CANNOT change".  I did see the other post but since I cannot change the calling routine I need to adjust the controller

Comment: @Joel remove the msg parameter and read the content directly **await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()** - then you will get string "msg=<whatever>"

Comment: Make edits as if the post was always like this. New readers don't know or care about its history, so the weird formatting would only confuse them. Also put effort to make your point clear: [ppl aren't going to spend their time to figure things out if it requires unreasonably much effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342154/648265).